# Ways to create reusable wpf elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm definitely new to wpf, and I wonder, what could I do with the following situation (for example):
I have a xaml markup file, and somewhere in that file I declare two `<Border>` elements, and each of them has nested elements:

```
<Border Grid.Row="1">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="1st el"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    </StackPanel>
</Border>

<Border Grid.Row="2">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="2nd el"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeVMProp}">
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Everything works fine, but this code seems to break DRY principle. So here're my questions:

- What's the correct way to refactor this code (I mean creating reusable element (StackPanel + Border))?
- What's the correct place to hold my reusable element code?
- What's the correct way to include my reusable element into xaml of concrete view?
- Any other suggestions about it?

PS *Sorry if my question is incorrect, but I'm expecting somebody to give me an idea about dealing with situations like that.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click your project, click New -> UserControl. Name it to whatever you want. Paste your XAML where you want it.

Use it in you MainWindow.xaml (or whatever your main window is called) by referencing `<local:MyUserControl/>`.

Answer (score -1):

You should develop custom control for this situation. 
You can have a custom control library. Take a look [this msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx)

Comment: Oh, are you kidding me? Are you serious? Should I really do such a lot of stuff to achieve it?

Comment: I'm expecting to do all this staff, using XAML only.